# If N is positive then output all values from N down to and excluding 0. If N is negative, then output every value from N up to and excluding 0

Tags: python

As I said before I'm a beginner trying to learn Python in a college course, but what they teach us, doesn't always apply to the real world, and when I try to research a solution, there's nothing to be found. Anyway my latest problem is:

```
This is a tricky challenge for you.

We will pass in a value N. N can be positive or negative.

If N is positive then output all values from N down to and excluding 0.
If N is negative, then output every value from N up to and excluding 0.

and the starting code is:

# Get N from the command line
import sys
N = int(sys.argv[1])

# Your code goes here
counter = 0
while counter <= N:
print(counter)
counter = counter + 1
elif counter >= N:
print(N+counter)
counter = counter - 1

My solution produced an error:

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
There is an error is your program.
```

And I honestly don't know where to start, as our textbook doesn't cover these challenges. Thanks in advance for any assistance rendered in this matter. BTW my code is inputted in Codio, and must pass in Codio's IDE.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: So, apparently you have a SyntaxError. HAve you tried fixing it?

Comment: You apparently already asked this question! How is this different from before?

Answer (score 1):

```
# Get N from the command line
import sys
N = int(sys.argv[1])

# Your code goes here
if N > 0:
    for x in range(N, 0, -1):
        print x
if N < 0:
    for x in range(N, 0):
        print x
```

While Loops Version

```
# Your code goes here
if N > 0:
    while N > 0:
        print N
        N -= 1
if N < 0:
    while N < 0:
        print N
        N += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance @joshuacockrell, greatly appreciated. My first question dealt with an 'while' statement and being that I haven't even begun learning about 'range' yet, this 'noobie' appreciates your time and knowledge.

Comment: @T.Mic Edited with while loop version

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that you have a while and an elif. Elif is used with other if statements.

For example:

```
if condition:
    do something
elif condtion:
    do something else
else:
    do something as a "last resort"
```

I think you are trying to do this:

```
#Checks To See if N is Positive
if N > 0:
    #Sets counter to 1
    counter = 1
    #Iterates Thru Each Num from 1 To N-1
    while counter < N:
        print counter
        #Increments Counter
        counter += 1
#Checks To See If N Is Negative
elif N < 0:
    #Sets Counter to -1
    counter = -1
    #Iterates Thru Each Num From -1 To N-1
    while counter > N:
        print counter
        #Decrements Counter
        counter -= 1
```

A couple final things:

- If you want to learn what you consider "real world" programming, then I suggest that you look at some online resources such as https://www.codecademy.com/ or looking through the docs.
- When posting on Stack Overflow, please explain your question/problem thoroughly
- When inputting your code on Stack Overflow, make sure that it is properly formatted (e.g. indentations), as they make decoding larger programs much easier.
- Stack Overflow is not a "do my homework for me" site